# How to run a java class with a jar in the classpath?

Tags: java, classpath

So, I can do this very well:

```
java mypackage.MyClass
```

if `./mypackage/MyClass.class` exists. I can also happily do this:

```
java -cp myjar.jar mypackage.MyClass
```

if the class file exists in the appropriate part of the jar. Easy stuff. But I can't for the life of me manage to do something like this:

```
java -cp utilities.jar mypackage.MyClass
```

where `./mypackage/MyClass.class` exists, and where `./utilities.jar` exists (not containing MyClass, of course).

Am I about to feel stupid?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Possibly :)

```
# On Unix
java -cp utilities.jar:. mypackage.MyClass

# On Windows
java -cp utilities.jar;. mypackage.MyClass
```

Basically that's just including `.` (the current directory) on the classpath as well as the jar file.

Comment: Is `-cp` a short form for `-classpath`?

Comment: @overexchange: Yes. (Running `java -?` would have told you that.)

Comment: this is not working for me....
```java -cp argparse4j-0.9.0.jar:. Demo
Error: Could not find or load main class Demo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Demo```

Comment: @rica01: Well is `Demo.class` in the current directory? We can't really tell much just from that. (And what operating system are you using?)

Comment: it was. I honestly gave up on this, it was taking tooooooo much time for something that should be extrasimple. thanks anyways jon!

Answer (score 8):

Try this if you're on Windows:

```
java -cp .;utilities.jar mypackage.MyClass
```

Or this if you're on Linux:

```
java -cp .:utilities.jar mypackage.MyClass
```

The current directory is not in the `CLASSPATH` by default when you specify a value for `-cp`.

Comment: No, the current directory *is* the classpath by default; it's only when you specify a *different* classpath that you get problems.

Comment: @Vuntic: That would certainly be accurate. Maybe @duffymo would like to edit to that wording :)

Answer (score 1):

The question seems dated. But there is no answer mentioning the feature of running source file directly without using `javac` first, applicable for JDK 11+.

On linux:

```
java -cp some-library.jar:some-other-library.jar AClassName.java
```

On windows:

```
java -cp "some-library.jar;some-other-library.jar" AClassName.java
```

Answer (score -1):

You should include the `mypackage.MyClass` into the `CLASSPATH` or the `-cp` parameter.
For example:

```
java -cp utilities.jar;myjar.jar mypackage.MyClass
```

The path separator is `;` on windows and `:` on Unix/Linux

Comment: that I can do just fine; MyClass is in a standalone class file, not myjar.jar