# Compile java program in command line with external .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, jar, javac

first of all, i've searched for some related topics, and already tried the solutions pointed in those, but still have some problems, so i'll try to explain it here hoping for a solution.

I'm trying to compile a java program which's already working on eclipse, on command line.
The .jar file and the java files are all in same directory, the class i'm trying to compile is NOT in the .jar, but in this class i used some methods belonging to that .jar (paillier.jar)

I first tried this:

```
javac -cp paillier.jar CoupleGen.java
java -cp paillier.jar CoupleGen
```

First line gives CoupleGen.class and no problems for the moment, when i type the second line it gives me the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class CoupleGen
```

So, reading some topics in here i tried another way

```
javac -cp paillier.jar CoupleGen.java
java -cp .;paillier.jar CoupleGen
```

and the result is a list of "how-to-use" java command with the end of these lines

```
paillier.jar command not found
```

So, i clearly make some mistakes, but actually i can't understand.
Just in case it's needed, i set up ambient variable.

Any help is really appreciated.

Cheers

Here's the code i'm trying to compile

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

import paillierp.key.KeyGen;
import paillierp.key.PaillierKey;
import paillierp.key.PaillierPrivateKey;


public class CoupleGen {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //Creo un messaggio m da criptare

        //for (int j=1; j==2; j++){

                int nodeID=5;
                int s=32;
                Random random = new Random();
                long seed = random.nextLong();
                PaillierPrivateKey pr= KeyGen.PaillierKey(s, seed);
                PaillierKey pu= pr.getPublicKey();
                System.out.println("PublicKey:("+pr.getN()+","+pr.getNPlusOne()+")");
                String pubkey ="PublicKey"+nodeID;
                    FileWriter File= new FileWriter(pubkey);
                    PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(File);
                    out.println("n:" + pu.getN());
                    out.println("n+1:" + pu.getNPlusOne());
                    out.println("n^s:" + pu.getNS());
                    out.println("n^s+1:" + pu.getNSPlusOne());
                //  out.println("rnd:" + pu.getRnd());
                    out.println("k:" + pu.getK());  
                    out.close();
        //} for not working on this pc
    }
}
```

Comment: java -cp ".;paillier.jar" CoupleGen

Comment: Windows or Linux? (hint: Linux uses : as the path separator)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409510/how-to-run-a-java-class-with-a-jar-in-the-classpath

Comment: first run set classpath=%classpath%;.; on command prompt and then do what you are already doing.

Comment: Used .: and :. but by the fact my class isn't contained in .jar it gives me the error

<code>
Error: Could not find or load main class CoupleGen
</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are executing below line, you are getting the below error right ?

javac -cp paillier.jar CoupleGen.java

Error: Could not find or load main class CoupleGen

That means compiler is looking for the CouplenGen.java in paillier.jar. Actually CoupleGen is outside of the jar file.

Comment: Do one thing, make one jar file using your entire project in the eclipse.

procedure for making jar file is

Comment: Do one thing, make one jar file using your entire project in the eclipse.

procedure for making jar file is
right click on your project->export->java->runnable jar file->click on next. Then select CoupleGen in launch configaration dropdown box -> select required libraries into generated jar ->finish.

Now open cmd ->goto the jar file path in cmd-> then give the command -> java -jar jarFileName.
thats it, it will execute automatically.

Comment: Ok, it worked, thank you very very much. The problem now is that i'll have to execute more of this java programs, i'll have to create one .jar file for everyone of em to execute em? Isn't there a way like javac->java?

Comment: i didn't get your question. what "em" means?
And give me some clarity, what is your requirement exactly?

Comment: em means other java programs. I'll explain myself better, i'm going to run some java program one after another, like, Couplegen.java for generating a couple of keys, Extract.java to extract keys from file. Depending on the situation, i have to create bash scripts (or something similar, still working on it) with those java programs.

Comment: if each .java file is an individual java project then create a jar file for each java program. Then write a code some thing like this in another java file. 
public class DriverProgram{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java -jar Demo.jar");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java -jar Demo1.jar");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java -jar Demo1.jar");

   }
}
The above program will execute jar files one by one in cmd promt.

Comment: Ok, you solved all my problems, thanks, thanks very much! Whishing you a merry Christmas :)

Comment: Thanks Elia and wish you the same. This is my first answers to the question in stackoverflow. Please click on appcet button (right mark). you can find the right mark at left to the first line of my answers. Such that ill get some reputation points.

Comment: Done, wish you the best :)

Answer (score 2):

`>> paillier.jar command not found`

This sounds like you're running this on Linux or Mac, and the command line interprets this as two different commands because of the semicolon `;`:

```
java -cp .
paillier.jar CoupleGen
```

The semicolon is used as path-separator on Windows only, on Linux and Mac one should use the colon `:`. So try running you're code like that:

```
java -cp .:paillier.jar CoupleGen
```

Comment: BarrySW19 beat me with a comment, but had the same idea.

Comment: (yep, running on xubuntu) with this colon it gives me the error

<code>
    Error: Could not find or load main class CoupleGen
</code>

And seeing another answer, i've to point out that my class isn't in paillier.jar

Answer (score 1):

```
javac -cp C:\...\yourjarfile.jar; javafile.java
```

This works in the Windows command prompt very easily. Do not forget to write `-cp`, **semicolon**(`;`) , `.jar`, `.java` extensions and later run it with `java C:\...\yourjavafile.java`. You can have you directory changed from `c` to `d` or `e`.