# Maven: "NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/newt/event/KeyListener"

Tags: java, maven, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to use the external jars JOGL and GlueGen in a Maven poject. The build process works, but when i execute the jar i get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/newt/event/KeyListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.jaamsim.ui.GUIFrame.main(GUIFrame.java:1995)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>JaamSim</groupId>
    <artifactId>JaamSim</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <nd4j.version>1.0.0-beta2</nd4j.version>
        <dl4j.version>1.0.0-beta2</dl4j.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.jaamsim.ui.GUIFrame</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- JOGL & Gluegen -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluegen-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I also tried building the jar with the shaded plugin and to install JOGL and GlueGen in the local repo, which yielded the same result.

Help to fix this problem is highly apreciated!

Comment: You may be missing another dependency - on the [`newt` artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jogamp.jogl/newt/2.3.2/jar) which defines the `KeyListener` interface.

Comment: @kidney No the version, the artifact ids and the group ids are correct except gluegen-rt that should be replaced by gluegen-rt-main, this is what I do in my example: https://jogamp.org/cgit/ardor3d.git/tree/pom.xml#n304 käyrätorvi is right, the dependencies aren't packaged with his program.

Answer (score 3):

Maven does not package the dependency classes in the final *.jar*. Some options:

- Manually add the dependencies to your classpath with the *-classpath* flag ([How to run a java class with a jar in the classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409510/how-to-run-a-java-class-with-a-jar-in-the-classpath)).
- Use Maven exec plugin which will generate a proper classpath ([How do I execute a program using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472376/how-do-i-execute-a-program-using-maven)).
- Create a "fat" jar with all the dependecies ([Maven build assembly with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615634/maven-build-assembly-with-dependencies)).