Java NoClassDefFoundError folder in path
Why am I getting the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex when I run a program from a Windows command line? I set the path to include the folder with commons-codec-1.5.jar. Is SET PATH=path_to_folder_with_commons;%PATH% not sufficient?

No, Java does not read the PATH variable from the OS for libraries, you have to specify the class_path when executing your program. I will mark this question as a duplicate. Look it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6409545/460557

btw Java now has java.util.HexFormat so you might not need the 3rd party library
